# Get SD card serial / oemid from U-boot on RaspberryPi3

Tags: u-boot

I'm using U-boot on raspberry pi 3 and I want to obtain SD card `oemid` or `serial` number.

"Normally" it can be done by accessing `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/` or by running `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdX` on linux site, but I wonder:

Is that possible via U-Boot (i.e. without running kernel) ?